# "Build Automatically" function with Swing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

How should I implement a function like that on my Swing editor?
I was thinking of a thread started on a `releaseKey` event. This thread should have a timer of a second. Every time I have the `releaseKey` I either start the thread or just reset the timer if it is already running.
I'm not convinced though. It seems like too heavy on the UI.
How should I do it?

Comment: Unless you are operating on the in memory buffer of your editor, you probably only want to "build" when the file is saved. If you try to build on every key stroke that will fall apart once you exceed what can be built between keystrokes. Reparsing the file I'm editing can work, for displaying syntax errors, etc, can work, but that can fail too with a large file and a series of quick changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Timer starting/stopping every second is not a big weight on the UI at all.  The "building" is what is going to possibly take some time.  I think looking for a pause in keystokes is a fine solution.

Comment: @Dierre, yes a Swing Timer just fires and event.  It is not a heavy load, but the action taken could be.

Comment: it's actually working very well associated to a DocumentListener where I launch timer.restart().